# What prompted Yasha to commit to Emilia all of a sudden?

Tags: yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer, the-magician-of-lublin

In *The Magician of Lublin*, when Yasha goes to meet his sweetheart Emilia, Emilia starts talking about how Yasha's being non-commital:

> ["...]About us I certainly couldn't tell you a thing. All our plans are suspended in the air. I'm afraid that everything will drag on like this until we're both old and gray...."
> "I've come to you now and we won't be separated again!" he said, amazed at his own words. Until now he had not yet made a decision.
> <sub>(translated by Elaine Gottlieb and Joseph Singer, 1960)</sub>

What prompted Yasha to suddenly make this decision? This obviously would involve abandoning his wife, and his assistant, and he obviously wasn't prepared to do that before this. Why, then, does he suddenly make this decision in response to Emilia's complaint? What other factors are at play here?